# spring 4 mvc + Hibernate + Annotations configuration Heap memory issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

The environment details are.

```
Intellij IDE
Spring 4
Hibernate with simple schema of 30 tables
Elastic search client
Mysql
CRUD operation repository classes
```

So my issue is at the time of the application start up itself the memory goes to 950MB which looks abnormal for me.

I am using annotation based configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import({ElasticSearchConfig.class})
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:sms_templates.xml")
    })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company"}, excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(value = {Controller.class, ControllerAdvice.class, RestController.class}, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(pattern = {"com\\.company\\.web\\..*"}, type = FilterType.REGEX)
})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
public class RootConfiguration {
```

Maven Deps

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.7.3</jackson.version>
    <spring_batch.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring_batch.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring_session.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring_session.version>
    <spring_security.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring_security.version>
    <java_mail.version>1.4</java_mail.version>
    <spring_data.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring_data.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
        <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>one.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>streamex</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_session.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${java_mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring_data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

can anyone please let me know the issue here, why it is going to such high heap usage. I am not loading any data onload other than light weight property files.

```
22:52:49,896  INFO localhost-startStop-1 context.ContextLoader:305 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
22:52:49,905  INFO localhost-startStop-1 support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:581 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Feb 09 22:52:49 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
22:52:50,046  INFO localhost-startStop-1 support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:207 - Registering annotated classes: [class com.company.config.RootConfiguration,class com.company.config.StandaloneRedisConfiguration]
22:52:50,685  INFO localhost-startStop-1 config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:166 - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
22:52:51,395  INFO localhost-startStop-1 config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:166 - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
22:52:51,420  INFO localhost-startStop-1 xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [security-context.xml]
22:52:51,683  INFO localhost-startStop-1 core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion:75 - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.1.3.RELEASE
22:52:51,683  INFO localhost-startStop-1 config.SecurityNamespaceHandler:78 - Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.1.3.RELEASE
22:52:51,755  INFO localhost-startStop-1 method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser:207 - Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
22:52:53,340  INFO localhost-startStop-1 config.RootConfiguration:47 - Messages loaded.
22:52:54,236  INFO localhost-startStop-1 jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:339 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
22:52:54,415  INFO localhost-startStop-1 hibernate.Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
22:52:54,419  INFO localhost-startStop-1 cfg.Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
22:52:54,423  INFO localhost-startStop-1 cfg.Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
22:52:54,938  INFO localhost-startStop-1 common.Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
22:52:55,741  INFO localhost-startStop-1 dialect.Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
22:52:55,773  INFO localhost-startStop-1 internal.LobCreatorBuilder:97 - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
22:52:56,610  INFO localhost-startStop-1 ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
22:52:56,742  INFO localhost-startStop-1 util.Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
22:52:58,866  INFO localhost-startStop-1 hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:182 - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
22:52:58,866  INFO localhost-startStop-1 hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:193 - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
22:52:58,888  INFO localhost-startStop-1 hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:205 - HHH000396: Updating schema
```

Comment: What is the error message?? If you are running it on server like tomcat, increase the permgen space.

Comment: I am not getting error message I wonder why it is taking that much memory, I am going to deploy on 2GB ram server in that case it will make issue so that makes me worry.

Comment: it jumps too high. But this kind of issue without hard numbers (which are easy to get with a profiler) seem like a wild goose chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching jvisualvm and Goto Profiler --> Memory tab or Sample --> Memory. You might get to see some objects which should not be present in that high number. Or else take a memory dump and use heap dump analyzer. That would give you a even more clear view of what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I can guarantee that your application is doing more than just loading some lightweight property files.  When spring boot sees libraries on the classpath, it will automatically load default configurations and generate a series of beans.

The increase in memory is most likely a product of precisely that.

You can certainly profile to be sure, if you feel compelled.

Comment: this makes sense to me but is there any way that can we restrict the generating the series of beans other than my application classes.
I think I kept component scan limited to my com.company packages in my annotation